# Input and Output Voltage of a Full bridge rectifier

Tags: voltage, ac

I know If we provide a sinusoidal AC Voltage across the Inputs of a full bridge rectifier we get a fluctuating DC Voltage (more or less) with the peaks of source AC Voltage. But what would be the peak voltage after smoothing the Output DC with Capacitors if we hypotactically provide 220VAC RMS?

Comment: Depends whether you're talking about an ideal case, or not (but in both cases it's about the same, peak). And of the "hypotactical" question. :-) (did you mean "hypothetical"?)

Comment: It would be the peak voltage of the 220 VAC. Do you know how to calculate that?

Comment: @Transistor Unfortunately, No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Relationship between sinusoidal peak, RMS and average (after rectification) values. Image source: [Learn About Electronics](https://learnabout-electronics.org/ac_theory/ac_waves02.php).*

The peak voltage of a sinusoidal voltage waveform is \$ \sqrt 2 V_{RMS} \$. Conversely \$ V_{RMS} = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} V_{peak} \$.

The RMS voltage can be considered that DC voltage which will give the same heating affect as the AC being considered. Since the power in a resistive load is given by \$ P = \frac {V^2} R \$ the RMS value is not the same as the average value.

Without smoothing capacitors the fullwave rectified DC will have the same RMS value as the AC waveform (ignoring losses in the rectifier).

[image]

*Figure 2. Smoothing capacitor ripple. Image source: [Electronics Notes](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/power-supply-electronics/capacitor-smoothing-circuits.php).*

The smoothing capacitor charges up on each peak of the rectified AC and supplies power to the circuit when the voltage falls away. See the linked article for how to size the smoothing capacitor.

Comment: I disagree. The average value of an AC is always equal to 0.

Comment: @Miss, fixed, thank you.

Comment: @Transistor So the peak Voltage after smoothing is also 230V or root 2 x Vrms ? I'm confused!. Enough with the hypothetical, what would voltage reading I'm supposed to get in a normal multimeter if I were to pull my probes across the outputs? would it be an average value or just peaks?

Comment: Figure 2 should make it clear enough that the capacitors will hold the peak voltage. With no load on the power supply you should see \$ 230\sqrt 2 \ \textrm V \$. Your capacitor voltage rating must be greater than this.

Answer (score 1):

The AC peak value for 220 rms is 220 / 0.707 or 311 volts peak . Through an full wave rectifier this would be 311 - 1.4 volts due to the recifier diodes that has a voltage drop of .7 volts per half cycle . The output ac peak would be 311- 1.4 = 309 volts peak at output which would be a positive peaks ripple voltage and not true DC .
The average or DC equivalent would be 309 peak voltage x 0.637 average = 196.8 volts average or the Dc component output . If your wish to have a more DC output then you add a capacitor of the right voltage value that has at least your peak voltage or more and a uf value that smoothes out your dc . The average of DC value here is taken to calculate the amps load equivalent. So a capacitor will be needed to get a proper DC output . The ripple voltage is found by calculating the frequency x RC/ts.
You can find a calculator on google that will give you ripple factor or voltage and the capacitor needed for your circuit.